# Cross-browser hiding of disabled="disabled" <option>

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

Is there a reliable way (CSS, JQuery, etc.) to completely hide a disabled 
`<option disabled="disabled">` on all major browsers?

I need it to be completely hidden instead of being only greyed out (like in IE).

**UPDATE**: There is no crossbrowser way of hiding disabled options. If you need an option removed, use Jquery's [detach()](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) as pointed out below by Kevin B. disabled options are no good thing.

Comment: Yes, remove it from the select until you want to show it.

Comment: I'm aware of that option, and it will work on any browser, but it's quite hard to implement. That's why I was wondering if there is an easier way to do it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, remove it from the select until you want to show it.

```
var options = $("#myselect option");

// to disable the option at index 3

options.eq(3).detach();

// to enable the option at index 3

options.eq(3).insertAfter(options.eq(2)); // assuming option at index 2 is still attached to the DOM
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/BdK4G/1/)

Comment: Now `detach()` seems exactly the right thing! I was worried of using `remove()`, because I need to re-show deleted options later... I will give that a try!

Comment: Don't worry, I'll check it out and let you know!

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe this

```
$('option[disabled="disabled"]').remove()​
```